# Issue with cognito social login for Apple

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-identity-js, amplify-auth-cognito

I have a website with social login (apple , google , facebook), the social logins are configured in cogntio user pool.

for the website to work it needs name and email from the providers to create account.

google and facebook works fine but for apple it either fails to get the name or email for the user.
i checked the scope for the login on apple page and it is proper

[image]

can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

I created a new userpool and made the name field optional,
with this im able to get the information required for login/signup and user can update the name from within the app